# Django 1.10 : view function() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django

This is my first django project and I'm struggling to finish it. 
I've been working to function that editing post. When user clicks button, it send no(int)for that article, and get information related to no and display on page. User can edit that post in the same form and when user click submit, it redirect to home.html

However, the function I made keep sending me an error message that it takes 2 arguments even though I did not use any function that takes 2 arguments.

Here is views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_article(request, article_no):
article = Article.objects.filter(pk=article_no)
form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=request.article)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, _('Article correctly saved.'))
    # If the save was successful, redirect to another page
    redirect_url = reverse('blog/home.html')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

else:
    form = ArticleForm(instance=request.article)

return (request, {'form': form}, context)
```

This is form in detail.html where send no value to edit_article.html

```
 <form action="{% url 'blog:edit_article' %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
   {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="no" value="{{ item.no }}" />
    <button type="submit">edit></button>
  </form>
```

Comment: But... that function clearly *does* take two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The `article_no` arg does not magically find its way into the function call via the POST submit. You need to provide it to the `url` tag:

```
{% url 'blog:edit_article' item.no %}
```

This assumes, of course, that you have a url pattern with an appropriate named group associated with this view/view name.

Answer (score 0):

If You are talking about this function, it does recieve more than one Arg, it recieves the No you are talking about, and the request object

```
def edit_article(request, article_no):
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view needs arguments you must give the arguments in the url templatetag, like this :

{% url 'accounts:detail_account' **username = username** %}